# How to tighten a pipe while keeping it at specific angle?

Tags: plumbing

A picture is worth 1000 words.

[image]

If I turn it upright, it starts leaking. There's not enough give to complete one more turn (I could turn it maybe 30 degrees more if I remove the shelf and push really hard). The pipe in the wall is - well, in the wall, can't be turned. The threaded piece of pipe leading to the tap is attached to it permanently. I used some teflon tape on the thread to make it watertight, but it only works when the two sides sit tightly together, and here, with the heater in the upright position the joint is really quite loose.

What do I need to do to fix this embarrassing problem?

Comment: What make and model of water heater? Perhaps there is a means to attach its fitting independently of the housing then reattach.

Comment: @Freiheit: It doesn't have a separate fitting - the tap part has a threaded hole for the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a compression fitting between the wall and that device. Tighten the compression fitting at whatever angle you want. That won't give you a flush mount though.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture doesn't quite give enough information. I think you are saying that whatever that box is (a water heater?) connects to a threaded pipe coming out of the wall. Am I right?

If so, the other end of that pipe is probably also threaded. Remove the water heater, then use a pipe wrench to remove the threaded pipe from the wall. Get a new pipe that is a bit longer.

FYI- Teflon tape isn't a sealant. The Teflon reduces the friction so that the joint can be tightened further than it could without.

Comment: Yes, it's a water heater and it connects to a pipe in the wall. Unfortunately removing the pipe from the wall would require quite a bit of masonry work, which I'd much rather avoid.

Comment: Is the pipe not threaded on both ends? If it is, you can just unscrew it using the piece sticking out of the wall.

Comment: The pipe in the wall is bent at straight angle (elbow joint), threaded on both ends, one connected to a pipe leading up to mains near the ceiling. And then, even if I connect the new, longer pipe, what guarantee do I have the span between "watertight" and "won't budge" positions covers an angle with the heater upright?

Comment: I suggest that you look in the installation guide for you water heater. I have a feeling that it's not mounted properly. The installation manual will probably give you a good clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: The manual mentions using an extender in case the pipe is too deep in the wall. I just hope I won't end up with this thing upside down after I tighten the extender...

Comment: The extender is almost certainly the Right Answer given what you've told us.

Comment: PTFE Thread seal tape is, in fact a sealant. I prefer dope for most uses, as I find it a better sealant, but properly applied, PTFE tape does deform to fill & seal the small voids in the threads. Here is a manufacturer link with instructions: http://cleanfit.com/blue_monster_ptfe_thread_seal_tape_70885.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You have no hope whatever of it not leaking if you've turned **past the end point and backed up.** You squish out whatever sealant you have, and then back up and leave a gap. It MIGHT seal if you remove it, apply pipe dope (or tape, but I have better luck with dope), and return it just to the point where it's upright (count turns as you remove it.) If it's actually less than half a turn from locking up hard, it should seal. If it's "really quite loose" there should be one more turn in it.

If you didn't remove the shelf, how did get it on at all? Or, how many turns have been made to this point? Your picture is somewhat less enlightening than it might be - I'm forced to guess that there is a threaded connection on the back of this heater, since the dangling pipe is not connected to anything.

Normally there is enough give in a threaded pipe installation to put things where they belong, but only if you get there and stop. Quite possibly there's enough to turn it all the way around clockwise to where it's upright if you apply the sort of force that's often needed in making up threaded pipe joints. Without experience, it can be hard to tell for sure if you're facing "any more will break this" or "this will be fine" in force levels. As such, hiring a plumber is sometimes actually the cheaper solution. There's also the option of a union, which permits things to be rotated without reference to threads, but if you can't get behind the wall, that's not much of a solution for your situation - it should, however, at least be mentioned in this thread.

I prefer pipe dope (a paste) over PTFE tape, having used both. At the moment, it's a PTFE pipe dope.

Comment: As for the shelf - I screwed the heater part on only after getting the tap part nearly tightened (the dangling pipe is the spout.) The pipe's thread is quite wide, like 3mm per turn or so, so the whole thing just sits tightly against the wall and won't budge more maybe 30 degrees further. Still, it's good five or so turns - over a centimetre of the thread caught.